Add maven wrapper to a maven project
I would like to know on how to add maven wrapper mvnw to an existing/new maven project.
How this can be done? Please help.

Have you read this?  https://maven.apache.org/wrapper/  It purports to explain how to set this up.

Steps:

Download Apache Maven from here.
Read here on how to install Apache Maven locally.
Go into your desired maven project and run this command: mvn wrapper:wrapper. This will setup the wrapper for your maven project.

That's all.
